# Copy Data from One workbook to another using column header

Tags: vba, excel

Does any one have a piece of code to copy from one excel WB to another based on column headers?

Update:
Sorry to all, I am new to this site and I hope you can forgive my ignorance.

Here is the code I have tried, based on other's posts (thank you, Simon!).

```
Sub copy_cols()

    Set SourceWS = Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
    Set TargetWS = Workbooks("Business Loader V7.1.xlsx").Worksheets(2)

For Each rgCell In SourceWS.Range("A1:AX1")

TargetWS.Columns(GetColumn(TargetWS, rgCell.Value)) = _
 SourceWS.Columns(GetColumn(SourceWS, rgCell.Value))
' I Have also tried this with no success:
' TargetWS.Columns(GetColumn(TargetWS, rgCell.Value)) = _
 SourceWS.Columns(GetColumn(SourceWS, rgCell.Column))

End Sub

Function GetColumn(GCSheet As Worksheet, ColumnName As String) As Integer
    Dim intCol As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    intCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ColumnName, GCSheet.Rows(1), 0)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        GetColumn = 0
    Else
        GetColumn = intCol
    End If
End Function
```

I am getting an error "ByRef argument type mismatch" on the first and 5th line (excluding the spaces when count) at TargetWS.Cells....

I also have this... which works, but I have to add in a bunch of .End(xlDown)'s to account for missing information so the whole column is copied (not just to the next cell WITH a value).  Do you have a better system to account for this?

```
Sub CopyHeaders()
    Dim header As Range, headers As Range

    Set SourceWS = Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
    Set TargetWS = Workbooks("Business Loader V7.1.xlsx").Worksheets(2)

    Set headers = SourceWS.Range("A1:AX1")

    For Each header In headers
        If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
           Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=TargetWS.Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value)) '.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next
```

As you can see, I have to add in .End(xlDown) for every blank cell.  Thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: give us more information and what you have tried so far

Comment: add a .value under that cell assignment i.e. ....cells.value = ....cells.value

You're also using the GetColumn function wrong: to get the column header, dont just use rgcell.value, use something like sourcews.cells(1,rgcell.column).value ... that will give you the column heading of the current cell

Comment: @Simon Thanks, I am throughly confused but i will try and sort out what you have said.  Are you refering to the above code or one of the other's listed below?

Comment: yeah refering above. Sorry i think i missread your code a bit... rgCell.value is a column heading I can see.... so you're wanting to copy an entire column? Use wsDestination.columns(GetColumn(...)) = wsSource.columns(GetColumn(...))

Comment: @Simon, Simon, I have updates the code and I am have problems with a "ByRef argument type mismatch" error on line 9 of the first code found above. What does intDestRow and intSourceRow do?  

I have tried a few different versions of editing the '(GetColumn(STUFF)) = ' line but I cannot seem to get this going.

Comment: The "getcolumn" takes two arguments, a worksheet, and a string... you're trying to pass an Integer (intSourceRow)

The intSourceRow and intDestRow are meant to represent the row numbers of where you copy the data to... but later on you're trying to copy a whole column... 

I think first step: understand what that "GetColumn" function does: it just returns a column number based on a string. 

Step 2: work out what you're going to do with that column number.

You're trying lots of different things and hoping for the best without really understanding what they all mean :)

Comment: Hi @Simon, Thanks again.  I totally get that the function GetColumn has two arguments; the first being a worksheet and the second being a string.  What is confusing is that even if I put in a worksheet into the code it still says argument type mismatch.  I have updates the code to read what I would think should work, but I am still getting errors.  Thanks again!

Comment: When you say you're passing a worksheet into the code, are you passing a worksheet object, a string literal representing the worksheet tab, or a string literal representing the codename? Because you want the first one: a worksheet object :)

Comment: ahh okay.  So what is the worksheet object... "Source.xlsx".Worksheets(1) AND "Business Loader V7.1.xlsx"... is this correct? 
@Simon

Comment: Well  you'd want Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets(1) ... that will return a worksheet object. 

Usually if you're refering to the workbook you're running code from, you'd just use ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)... Or you can use ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") (i.e. provide the tab name) or you can just refer to its code name: each worksheet has a "codename" as specified in VBA properties: so if your sheet has a codename of "horse" then you can just use ThisWorkbook.horse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should be able to be altered to suit your needs...

```
Sub CopyByHeader()

    Dim SourceWS As Worksheet
    Set SourceWS = Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
    Dim SourceHeaderRow As Integer: SourceHeaderRow = 1

    Dim TargetWS As Worksheet
    Set TargetWS = Workbooks("Business Loader V7.1.xlsx").Worksheets(2)
    Dim TargetHeader As Range
    Set TargetHeader = TargetWS.Range("A1:AX1")

    Dim RealLastRow As Long
    Dim SourceCol As Integer

    SourceWS.Activate            
    For Each Cell In TargetHeader
        SourceCol = SourceWS.Rows(SourceHeaderRow).Find _
            (Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        If SourceCol <> 0 Then
            RealLastRow = SourceWS.Columns(SourceCol).Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            SourceWS.Range(Cells(SourceHeaderRow + 1, SourceCol), Cells(RealLastRow, _
                  SourceCol)).Copy
            TargetWS.Cells(2, Cell.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

UPDATE: Some errors with headers not in source sheet or empty columns.
It's also worth noting that with this code - you have to have 'Source.xlsx' open to read from it.

UPDATED CODE:

```
Sub CopyByHeader()

    Dim CurrentWS As Worksheet
    Set CurrentWS = ActiveSheet

    Dim SourceWS As Worksheet
    Set SourceWS = Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
    Dim SourceHeaderRow As Integer: SourceHeaderRow = 1
    Dim SourceCell As Range

    Dim TargetWS As Worksheet
    Set TargetWS = Workbooks("Business Loader V7.1.xlsx").Worksheets(2)
    Dim TargetHeader As Range
    Set TargetHeader = TargetWS.Range("A1:AX1")

    Dim RealLastRow As Long
    Dim SourceCol As Integer

    SourceWS.Activate
    For Each Cell In TargetHeader
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            Set SourceCell = Rows(SourceHeaderRow).Find _
                (Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not SourceCell Is Nothing Then
                SourceCol = SourceCell.Column
                RealLastRow = Columns(SourceCol).Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
                If RealLastRow > SourceHeaderRow Then
                    Range(Cells(SourceHeaderRow + 1, SourceCol), Cells(RealLastRow, _
                        SourceCol)).Copy
                    TargetWS.Cells(2, Cell.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    CurrentWS.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: I am having trouble getting this to work.  On the 14th line there is an error "Object variable or With block variable not set".  In my VBA, Cell.Value is not capatalizing the cell part  so it looks like (cell.Value... instead of (Cell.Value...

Comment: I've added the SourceWS.Activate line to the code. This maybe the cause of the error; it's working for me within a single workbook between sheets but check and see if it works for you across your workbooks

Comment: Hi @Flephal, I feel as though this is close, however it is giving me some trouble at the "SourceWS.Range(Cells(... " line.  The error message is "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed".

Comment: Altered to take out the requirement for 'SourceWS.' in the code. I've found over the years that code across worksheets can be a bit cumbersome to get working properly as what seems to be viable coding just doesn't work as it should... Hopefully the edits should now work!!!

Comment: Hi @Flephal, I am sorry my friend, I had edited the post just before you edited the code to say: "THANK YOU!! It works like a dream! Thank you thank you thank you. "  But for some reason the edit did not stick.  

My issue was that I did not have Source.xlsx as the foremost excel workbook, when I clicked on the WB and made it active, it worked perfectly.

Comment: I was trying to look at what you changed and I cannot see any difference between what I have in my VBA and what you posted here.

Comment: actually, I posted to the section below this one.  
Thanks again @Flephal

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Function GetColumn(GCSheet As Worksheet, ColumnName As String) As Integer
    Dim intCol As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    intCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ColumnName, GCSheet.Rows(1), 0)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        GetColumn = 0
    Else
        GetColumn = intCol
    End If
End Function
```

Use that for your source worksheet and your destination. You could also use "Find". This assumes your columns are in row 1.

Then it's just a case of

```
wsDestination.cells(intDestRow, GetColumn(wsDestination, "ColumnName")).value = _
    wsSource.cells(intSourceRow,GetColumn(wsSource, "ColumnName")).value
```

Comment: or 'for each rgCell in SourceHeader, Destination.cells(intDestRow, GetColumn(wsDestination, rgCell.value) = wsSource.cells(intSourceRow, rgCell.column)

Comment: Hi @Simon, thanks for the comments, I have not attempted to implement your code just yet.  I have an answer I would like to have your input on, however I cannot

Comment: hmm might not have enough rep to answer your own question or something... see how you go, if yer still stuck make a new post all together I guess :)

Comment: thanks so much for all of your help, I have edited the original post to give you a better context as to what I am tying to achieve.  Thanks again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Flephal!  It works!!!!!!!  Thanks so much!!!  this is the best.  Now if I can only get the "GetColumn" function working from above and I will be one happy fellow.