# .find VBA Macro Finding text in one column and add conditional text to the adjacent column

Tags: vba, excel

Just wondering if anyone could solve this problem quicker and neater than I did.  Also, it seems cumbersome, so a smoother process would help.  And it doesn't seem to work all the time, its adding data into other columns I had not intended it to.

My problem is that I need to enter data into column P based on the supplied information from column O.  Column O has the heading "Job_Title" while P is "Job_Function".  There are a few key words I use to do this as you will see in the code.  Is there a better Guard for the loop? Is there a better loop?? Is there a neater, quicker code that doesnt add extra data into other columns?

Thanks for any assistance you can offer.  Also, see image for reference to the extra data being added to other columns.

```
 Sub Enter_Job_Function()
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim count1 As Integer
 Dim count2 As Integer   ' the counters are for the message box to let me know how many items were added/modified

i = 2

Do Until i = 300 

On Error Resume Next
    Cells(i, 16).Find(What:="Architect").Offset(0, 1) = "Architect"
    Cells(i, 16).Find(What:="Manager").Offset(0, 1) = "Manager"
    Cells(i, 16).Find(What:="Mgr").Offset(0, 1) = "Manager"
    Cells(i, 16).Find(What:="Director").Offset(0, 1) = "Director"
    Cells(i, 16).Find(What:="Dir").Offset(0, 1) = "Director"
    Cells(i, 16).Find(What:="Dir,").Offset(0, 1) = "Director"
    Cells(i, 16).Find(What:="Chief").Offset(0, 1) = "Executive"
    Cells(i, 16).Find(What:="CIO").Offset(0, 1) = "Executive"
    Cells(i, 16).Find(What:="CTO").Offset(0, 1) = "Executive"
    Cells(i, 16).Find(What:="CEO").Offset(0, 1) = "Executive"
    Cells(i, 16).Find(What:="Vice President").Offset(0, 1) = "VP"
    Cells(i, 16).Find(What:="VP").Offset(0, 1) = "VP"


i = i + 1
On Error GoTo 0
Loop

Dim j As Integer ' This loop is for a separate column, this is also malfunctioning in a major way so any advise would be much appreciated. 
j = 1
Do Until j = 20
j = j + 1
    Cells(j, 16).Find(What:="Technology").Offset(0, 2) = "Information Technology"

Loop

PromptDialog.Hide
MsgBox i & " item(s) modified out of a possible " & i & " item(s)" ' I know this is not going to work as is, again, any advise would be awesome...

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry, no picture, I am not cool enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably make use of a dictionary item for the main loop. It adds a bit of readability to the code.

```
Sub Enter_Job_Function()

    Dim JobDictionary As Object
    Set JobDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    JobDictionary.Add "Architect", "Architect"
    JobDictionary.Add "Manager", "Manager"
    JobDictionary.Add "Mgr", "Manager"
    JobDictionary.Add "Director", "Director"
    JobDictionary.Add "Dir", "Director"
    JobDictionary.Add "Dir,", "Director"
    JobDictionary.Add "Chief", "Executive"
    JobDictionary.Add "CIO", "Executive"
    JobDictionary.Add "CTO", "Executive"
    JobDictionary.Add "CEO", "Executive"
    JobDictionary.Add "Vice President", "VP"
    JobDictionary.Add "VP", "VP"

    Dim Modified As Integer

    For i = 2 To 300
        If JobDictionary.Exists(Cells(i, 16).Value) Then
            Cells(i, 17).Value = JobDictionary.Item(Cells(i, 16).Value)
            Modified = Modified + 1
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 20
        If Cells(i, 16).Value = "Technology" Then
            Cells(i, 18) = "Information Technology"
            Modified = Modified + 1
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next i

    MsgBox Modified & " item(s) modified out of a possible " & j & " item(s)"
End Sub
```

UPDATE:
To take into account substring searches (Removed "Dir," as "Dir" will cover these as well)

```
Sub Enter_Job_Function()

    Dim JobDictionary As Object
    Set JobDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    JobDictionary.Add "Architect", "Architect"
    JobDictionary.Add "Manager", "Manager"
    JobDictionary.Add "Mgr", "Manager"
    JobDictionary.Add "Director", "Director"
    JobDictionary.Add "Dir", "Director"
    JobDictionary.Add "Chief", "Executive"
    JobDictionary.Add "CIO", "Executive"
    JobDictionary.Add "CTO", "Executive"
    JobDictionary.Add "CEO", "Executive"
    JobDictionary.Add "Vice President", "VP"
    JobDictionary.Add "VP", "VP"

    Dim Modified As Integer

    For i = 2 To 300
        For Each Item In JobDictionary.Keys
            If InStr(Cells(i, 16).Value, Item) Then
                Cells(i, 17).Value = JobDictionary.Item(Item)
                Modified = Modified + 1
            End If
        Next
        j = j + 1
    Next

    For i = 1 To 20
        If InStr(Cells(i, 16).Value, "Technology") Then
            Cells(i, 18) = "Information Technology"
            Modified = Modified + 1
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next

    MsgBox Modified & " item(s) modified out of a possible " & j & " item(s)"
End Sub
```

Comment: This is prefect!  It searches for the "substrings" and places the corresponding text into the adjcent column.  Thank you.

Comment: The count is a few off if there are not any changes, but this is an easy fix.  thank you again.

Comment: Yes - the count could easily be out as there is no real control over how many times the value next to it is modified. i.e. if 'Director' is present both 'Dir' and 'Director' will cause value changes and modified will increment by 2. (I should have removed the 'Director' entry as well as 'Dir,'. Likewise 'Architect VP' would cause 2 hits. There are a number of ways around this depending on how you want to control the values. But as an example it's a fairly good place to start...

Comment: Perfect, I am really happy with this code.  Thank you very much.  Perhaps you might feel inclined to help me with another tricky (for me) problem.  I have also posted this on the forum here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474279/copy-data-from-one-workbook-to-another-using-column-header

here is the link to my other problem...

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this (tried to stick to your style):

```
Sub Enter_Job_Function()

  Dim i As Integer
  Dim TotalItems As Integer
  Dim StartRow As Integer
  Dim EndRow As Integer
  Dim NotModified As Integer
  Dim Modified As Integer

  StartRow = 2
  EndRow = 300
  TotalItems = EndRow - StartRow + 1

  For i = StartRow To EndRow

    If Cells(i, 16).Value = "Architect" Then
      Cells(i, 17).Value = "Architect"
    ElseIf Cells(i, 16).Value = "Manager" Then
      Cells(i, 17).Value = "Manager"
    ElseIf Cells(i, 16).Value = "Mgr" Then
      Cells(i, 17).Value = "Manager"
    '
    'other conditions here
    '
    Else: NotModified = NotModified + 1 'count how many weren't modified (easier to do it this way)
    End If

  Next i

  'do a similar thing for other column here

  Modified = TotalItems - NotModified 'work out how many we have modifed

  MsgBox ("Modified " & Modified & " out of a possible " & TotalItems)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Guys, Sorry, I forgot to mention the real problem here is that (I think) there is a need to use the .find(what:=   ) command as the cell contains text such as "Dir Infrastructure Services".  Therefore, using cell values will find cells with only "Dir" in the formula bar. In this case, the operation will skip right over the cell I want it to perform the function on.

Comment: In that case you should probably add the optionals LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart to your find functions

Comment: Thanks @Flephal, the answer works like a dream.  and it looks nice too.